# swift: delegate is nil after segue

Tags: delegates, protocols, segue, null

I have a center ViewCentroller with a button to another ViewController. In the first file I also declare a protocol. This delegate works just fine in the first ViewCentroller, but after the segue has been performed, the delegate is nil. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First way is to use `prepareForSegue` and declare in it all your `delegate` methods.

Second way is to use `NSNotificationCenter` and with this transfer your delegate so this works with `pushToViewController`